# Error while import pyfftw

Tags: python, importerror, pyfftw

I am getting following error while importing pyfttw , (windows 10 64-bit,cpython 64 bit):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyfftw\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .pyfftw import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: Not possible find the specified module.
```

I've installed pyfftw whl file with pip and instal successful.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

pyfftw is just a wrapper , you need to install FFTW :
http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

Comment: Ok how can i install it and use with python? Thanks in advance

Comment: download the compiled version , you could  put the DLLs near your python script ( if that  doesn't work put it in C:/windows/system , that folder contains DLLs that every application should be able to use ) tell me if it worked for you

Comment: Ok i've download the 64-bit dll, i've copied it in system but nothing, in syswow64 nothing. Thanks in advance for your kind support

Comment: Sorry for the late answer , had to search for a windows VM .
do you have any specific reason to use python3 ? i used python 2 , installed numpy and pyfftw with pip and it worked like a charm on my windows 7 64 bits VM, also could you check "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyfftw" to see if you have these 3 files : libfftw3-3.dll libfftw3f-3.dll libfftw3l-3.dll

Comment: Ok I've added the three dlls files into directory " C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyfftw" and I also have reboot. Nothing.

Comment: I have a news , if before to import pyfftw I use import numpy , i don't get any error. Why?

Comment: I don't have any idea man , makes no sense to me , but i'm happy i somehow helped to make it work for you :)

Comment: Oh, are you using Anaconda? [This is a known issue](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/40) due to Anaconda using MKL which tries to provide all the same symbols that FFTW does.

Comment: Can you try to use python2, pyfftw is a python2 library that is compatible with python3 , could be a compatibility issue